# Laravel blade Route with vue data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Here's the deal, I'm using blade and vue.js together on my Laravel app, and I need to build a url for my anchor tag...
With blade only, what I would do was:

```
{{ Route('chef.menus.show', [$shop, $menu]) }}
```

Since my route is

```
Route::get('/lojas/{shop}/cardapios/{menu}', 'MenuController@show')
->name('chef.menus.show');
```

But, since I'm not using blade **@foreach** to render my links, and I'm using **v-for**. What is the best way to build a url from a Route name (if it is possible) inside here:

```
<tr v-for="menu in menus">
                        <td>@{{ menu.id }}</td>
                        <td><a href="**URL GOES HERE**">@{{ menu.name }}</a></td>
                        <td>@{{ menu.items.length }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons md-16">delete</i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="material-icons md-16">edit</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Keep in mind that I need to pass {{$shop}} (from PHP) and @{{ menu.slug }} from vue.js to correctly build my url :(

I appreciate any help!
Thank you very much

Comment: You can't do what you're asking. PHP renders on the server side, Vue typically renders on the client side. So you need to either build your routes entirely in PHP or entirely in JavaScript. Not half and half.

Comment: Hmm that's true. I just didn't like that, since I'm going with vue, I have to hardcode most of the url, and I really do make a lot use of the Routes name, cause all my code is in english, but my url need to be in portuguese.. I'm doomed to do something like (v-bind:href="'/cardapios/' + menu.slug") aren't I?

Comment: When I've come up against this before, I have created a routes file for my SPA too, which shares the same route structure, names and parameters as my Laravel routes.

Comment: So should I take a look on vue routing? I'm really new to vue haha, thanks for your help!

Comment: That's a very broad question, more so given the little information about your application in your question. If you're still using server rendered pages, then that may not help you.